# Pandas - check categorisation of data using word matches in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

checking the categorisation of data by using key word matches:

When I use:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Info': ['Cat named Charlie', 'Dog named Barney', 'Fish named Paul and Cat named Franky'], 'Category_Animal' : 'Cats', 'Dog', 'Fishes'})`

`df['Animal_Match'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join([ i for i in x['Info'].split() if i in x['Category_Animal'].split()]),axis=1)`

I get the Output:

| Info | Category_Animal | Animal_Match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat named Charlie | Cat | Cat |
| Dog names Barney | Dog | Dog |
| Fish named Paul and Cat named Franky | Fish | Fish |

I want to check over all 'Category_Animals' and create a list storing these matches in Animal_Match:

so that ['Fish, 'Cat'] is the 'Animal_Match' output for the last row, not just 'Fish'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.str.findall`:

```
df["Animal_Match"] = df["Info"].str.findall("|".join(df["Category_Animal"]))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                   Info Category_Animal Animal_Match
0                     Cat named Charlie             Cat        [Cat]
1                      Dog names Barney             Dog        [Dog]
2  Fish named Paul and Cat named Franky            Fish  [Fish, Cat]
```

In case if you want to match more than the exact word:

```
df["Animal_Match"] = df["Info"].str.findall("|".join(df["Category_Animal"] + "[a-z]*"))
print(df)
```

Output (See the newly added last row)

```
                                   Info Category_Animal  Animal_Match
0                     Cat named Charlie             Cat         [Cat]
1                      Dog names Barney             Dog         [Dog]
2  Fish named Paul and Cat named Franky            Fish   [Fish, Cat]
3                       Dog named Doggo            Fish  [Dog, Doggo]
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you! Is there also a way of incorporating a str.contains kind of method here so that 'Dogs' or 'Doggo' in Info would match with 'Dog' in Category Animal?

Comment: Since `str.findall` uses regex, it will catch `Dogs`, `Doggo` or anything that _contains_ word in `Category_Animal`. What it cannot do is the yield the full match; `Doggo` will be included as `Dog` in the final match, excluding `go` part. If that's what you want, I've updated my answer ;)